# reset only one branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

When I reset one branch, it also is resetting the others. For example, say I have been working on `featureA` for a while, and I need to start on a new feature. So naturally I do

```
git branch featureB
git checkout featureB
```

Oh no, all my edits from `featureA` are here! So I do `git reset -hard upstream/dev` or `git checkout -- .` Seems to work, gets rid of all `featureA` stuff. But then when I'm done and I want to go back...

```
git checkout featureA
git status
```

All my work on `featureA` is now gone. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in the `featureA` branch when you create the `featureB` branch?  If so that makes sense that all your `featureA` stuff is there.

You should branch off your dev branch such as

```
git checkout -b featureB dev
```

which will create your branch off of your dev branch, as opposed to a continuation of the featureA branch.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --hard` is a destructive operation, and it is advised not to use it if you do not know what you are doing.

To save your work before checking you branch you can do

```
git stash
```

When you return you can reapply your changes with `git stash pop`.

If you haven't committed you changes in feature A than it is lost. If you did, you can check `git reflog` for the commit hash that you want to return to.

Comment: I know that it's destructive, I was just surprised that it acts outside of the current branch though.

Comment: If you haven't commited the change your changes never belonged to the branch.